# gcd$(a,b)=5$ what are the relations of $a$ and $b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I would be very grateful for any hints and corrections

I'm trying to prove in which relations are $a$ and $b$ whose gcd is $5$

Reflexive function is when $a$ in relation with $a$ is and that can be only when $a$ is $5$, so function is not reflexive?
It is symmetrical, because $aRb$ and $bRa$
Then it isn't antisymmetrical
And is not transitive, because not for every $a,b,c$ worth the $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $aRc$, if it would be about numbers $a = 5, b = 15$ and $c = 30$, then it doesn't fulfil the condition that $\gcd(b,c)= 5$

Comment: Yes it is not reflexive because it would be $gcd(a,a)=5$ $\forall a$. About the transitivity property you should verify that, supposing that $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $aRc$, so your backhoe is not the right choice to show this or eventually the contrary, because in this case $gcd(b,c)=15\neq 5$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does that mean that it isn't transitive because it doesn't apply for each possible a,b and c?

Comment: I mean that that blackhoe cannot be a neither a prove or a disprove of transitivity because you have to start at least with $aRb$ AND $bRc$ and then you have to prove that $aRc$, but in your case $b\not \mathrel{R}c $

Comment: Ohh yeah, that is true..but if a = 15 and b = 5 c = 30, then aRb and bRc but not aRc

Comment: @comfortably_numb now yes! This is counterexample for the transitivity

Comment: @willie thank you for help :)